# How to show Json using Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am learning AngularJS and have the structure of the project set up but JSON i can't display that in the html.

i am new in Angularjs. how to show JSON to data in my html using ng-repeat directive. my HTML is :

Anybody suggest me how to use json.?

---

```
    <div ng-repeat="qd in quiz">
        <p>{{qd.question}} </p>
        <p>{{qd.id}} </p>
        <ul>
          <li>{{qd.possibilities[0]}} </li>
          <li>{{qd.possibilities[1]}} </li>
          <li>{{qd.possibilities[2]}} </li>
          <li>{{qd.possibilities[3]}} </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

script:

```
    myApp.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.quiz = [{
            question: "1 what is the typical lifespan of a green sea turtle ?",
            id: 1,
            possibilities: [{
                    answer1: "150 years"
                },
                {
                    answer2: "10 years"
                },
                {
                    answer3: "80 years"
                },
                {
                    answer4: "40 years"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            question: "2 what is the typical lifespan of a green sea turtle ?",
            id: 2,
            possibilities: [{
                    answer1: "250 years"
                },
                {
                    answer2: "20 years"
                },
                {
                    answer3: "160 years"
                },
                {
                    answer4: "20 years"
                }
            ]
        }
    ];


}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this,

```
 <div ng-repeat="qd in quiz">
            <p>{{qd.question}} </p>
            <ul ng-repeat="(key,value) in qd.possibilities">

                <li>{{value["answer"+($index+1)]}} </li>
            </ul>
  </div>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.quiz = [{
        question: "1 what is the typical lifespan of a green sea turtle ?",
        id: 1,
        possibilities: [{
                answer1: "150 years"
            },
            {
                answer2: "10 years"
            },
            {
                answer3: "80 years"
            },
            {
                answer4: "40 years"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        question: "2 what is the typical lifespan of a green sea turtle ?",
        id: 2,
        possibilities: [{
                answer1: "250 years"
            },
            {
                answer2: "20 years"
            },
            {
                answer3: "160 years"
            },
            {
                answer4: "20 years"
            }
        ]
    }
];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='appCtrl'>
    <div class="row">
        <div ng-repeat="qd in quiz">
            <p>{{qd.question}} </p>
            <ul ng-repeat="(key,value) in qd.possibilities">
            
                <li>{{value["answer"+($index+1)]}} </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, 
but it show a full value like a object.
and i want only answer like "150 years"

Is my json is wrong ?

Comment: @user1727852 why did you remove?

Comment: sorry for this. but i am not understand. what you say. (means : what is remove)
your answer is very helpful for me.

plz solve my 1 more problem 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511846/how-to-get-data-from-a-php-webapi-json-to-using-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your script like this then it will be easy to achieve what you want:

```
$scope.quiz = [{
    question: "1 what is the typical lifespan of a green sea turtle ?",
    id: 1,
    possibilities: [{
      option: "150 years"
    }, {
      option: "10 years"
    }, {
      option: "80 years"
    }, {
      option: "40 years"
    }]
  }, {
    question: "2 what is the typical lifespan of a green sea turtle ?",
    id: 2,
    possibilities: [{
      option: "250 years"
    }, {
      option: "20 years"
    }, {
      option: "160 years"
    }, {
      option: "20 years"
    }]
  }];
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="possibilty in qd.possibilities">{{possibilty.option}}</li>
</ul>
```

Working demo: [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/cLNDek8JU95ASNaMcyii?p=preview)

**EDIT**

And if you don't want to change your script, use this:

```
<ul>
    <li>{{qd.possibilities[0].answer1}} </li>
    <li>{{qd.possibilities[1].answer2}} </li>
    <li>{{qd.possibilities[2].answer3}} </li>
    <li>{{qd.possibilities[3].answer4}} </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @user1727852: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.quiz = [{
        question: "1 what is the typical lifespan of a green sea turtle ?",
        id: 1,
        possibilities: [{
                answer1: "150 years"
            },
            {
                answer2: "10 years"
            },
            {
                answer3: "80 years"
            },
            {
                answer4: "40 years"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        question: "2 what is the typical lifespan of a green sea turtle ?",
        id: 2,
        possibilities: [{
                answer1: "250 years"
            },
            {
                answer2: "20 years"
            },
            {
                answer3: "160 years"
            },
            {
                answer4: "20 years"
            }
        ]
    }];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat="qd in quiz">
    <p>{{qd.question}} </p>
    <ul ng-repeat="item in qd.possibilities">
      <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in item">{{value}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  </div>
```