# How to get data of php Web api json from server to using AngularJs.?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, asp.net-web-api

When I am saving this json in my local computer and use it in my AngularJs script. It's work fine. But when I am using direct server to this it is not working - why?

What is missing in my script?

My Json file:

```
http://deals.ownaroof.com/api/webservices/locations_list.json
```

Html:

```
<div ng-controller='preferredCtrl'>{{locations}}</div>
```

Script >

```
(function(){
angular.module('myapp',['ngRoute'])
//afactory to consume webservices and return data to controllers.
.service('webServices',['$http',function($http){
    return {
        getLocations : function(){
            return  $http.get('http://deals.ownaroof.com/api/webservices/locations_list.json').then(function(response){ //wrap it inside another promise using then
                return response.data.response.locations;  //only return locations 
            });
        }
    }
}])
//define controller and inject webServices service as dependency.
.controller('preferredCtrl',['webServices','$scope',function(webServices,$scope,$ngRoute){ 
    webServices.getLocations().then(function(response){ 
        $scope.locations = response; //Assign data received to $scope.data
    });
}]) 
})();
```

How to use this json file anyone please suggest any solution.

Comment: do you see the data in console?

Comment: not show

there are a error

angular.min.js:102 Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/ng/areq?p0=axajCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

Comment: that is zip file
http://webstrokes.in/json-error.zip

plz sir help me.

Comment: something is wrong with your code part which is not mentioned above......

Comment: yes but what ? 
i don't know what are missing or
what is the right code, parameters, and what  ever. for call a json online to another file. 
plz help me if you know.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i am Hoping [This plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5YGVLQRpWVvgOOy7x6oY?p=preview) will be helpful to you.
As i cross origin issues i save the response in a json file and did this work around like

```
$http.get('j1.json').success(function(response){ //make a get request to mock json file.
            $scope.data = response; //Assign data recieved to $scope.data
            console.log($scope.data);
        })
```

Let me know if you have any queries on this

I used your json and simply displayed id and name of your data using ng-repeat [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/xpytfTI2PvUPKrLAKUZZ?p=preview)......let me know in which way you want to show this in your html like simple data or you want to show then in a drop down ????

Comment: that is right code but
my problem is 
how to get data using online json path to my another SPA.

Comment: that is log comment

------------------------
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://deals.ownaroof.com/api/webservices/locations_list.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Thats what i mentioned in my answer that i am getting cross origin issues.....try to over come that then your code will work fine

Comment: this is my all code
http://webstrokes.in/json-error.zip
can you check it and plz solve my problem
because i am not getting appropriate resulte.
and nither i konw what's is right script.
there are index1.html working fine but index.html working not.

Comment: but my problem is not solve
how to use json in html using angularjs

Comment: how you want to display your json in html??